# validate_inclusion_of using a list from a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a rail model, let's call it Item. In the db I have a list of items. Therefore I can do a

```
item = Item.find(28)
```

and get an object representing the item found in the database.

Now, I also have another Model, let's say Order that needs to do a validate_inclusion_of for one of its fields, to see if the item name is in the Item database.
Something like

```
validates: item_name, :presence => true
:inclusion => Item.all.name #get an array of all possible item names
```

Can this be done? What would be the nicest way of doing that?

Best Regards,

O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates_inclusion_of :item_name, :in => Proc.new{Item.select(:name).map(&:name)}
```

UPDATE

this is a the full implementation:

```
rails new shop
cd shop
rails g model item name:string
rails g model order item_name:string
rake db:migrate
```

now in your order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_name
  validates_inclusion_of :item_name, :in => Proc.new{Item.select(:name).map(&:name)}
end
```

now we need to test this in console

```
rails c
```

and in console

```
Item.create(name: 'book')
o = Order.new
o.valid?
=> false
o.errors
=> @messages={:item_name=>["is not included in the list"]}
o.item_name = 'book'
o.valid?
=> true
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Now, this looks just as good as Proc.new{Item.all.map(&:name)}. Right?

Comment: Actualy it doesnt seem to work here. I can set the item to a value not valid and get a item.valid? to true and be able to save the item. when doing item. item.errors returns null, whatever the value of item, as long as it is not null.

Comment: sorry but i cant understand your comment.. first of all, are you validating item or order model?

Comment: updated the answer with full implementation. sorry if it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Ahah, I found my error. stupidest ever, I was doing validates_presence_of :item_name , :in => {etc....} instead of validates_inclusion_of. Sorry about that. But you did teach me things, so thanks a lot for that. Cheers.